# Why np.array([1e5])**2 is different from np.array([100000])**2 in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, exponent

May someone please explain me why `np.array([1e5])**2` is not the equivalent of `np.array([100000])**2`? Coming from Matlab, I found it confusing!

```
>>> np.array([1e5])**2
array([  1.00000000e+10])   # correct

>>> np.array([100000])**2
array([1410065408])         # Why??
```

I found that this behaviour starts from **1e5**, as the below code is giving the right result:

```
>>> np.array([1e4])**2
array([  1.00000000e+08])   # correct

>>> np.array([10000])**2
array([100000000])          # and still correct
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1e5` is a floating point number, but 10000 is an integer:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.array([1e5]).dtype
Out[2]: dtype('float64')

In [3]: np.array([10000]).dtype
Out[3]: dtype('int64')
```

But in numpy, integers have a fixed width (as opposed to python itself in which they are arbitrary length numbers), so they "roll over" when they get larger than the maximum allowed value.

(Note that in your case you are using a 32-bit build, so in fact the latter would give you `dtype('int32')`, which has a maximum value 2**32-1=2,147,483,647, roughly 2e9, which is less than 1e10.)

Comment: ah, thank you! I found this info after reading your answer: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: Is there a possibility to set the 64-bit buid as default at the beginning of the code? Or I have to install the 64-bit build or NumPy?
I am asking this, in order to not change all the arrays in a long written code. Thanks

Comment: it's different versions of numpy (and possibly different versions of python?).

Answer (score 2):

You're system is defaulting to np.int32, which can't handle `100000**2`. If you use 64-bit precision, you'll be fine:

```
In [6]: np.array([100000], dtype=np.int32)**2
Out[6]: array([1410065408], dtype=int32)

In [7]: np.array([100000], dtype=np.int64)**2
Out[7]: array([10000000000])
```

What the default is (32 vs 64) depends on your numpy build.